# discord.py how to get last message

Tags: python, discord.py

I am using discord.py 2.1.0 and I want to get last message in channel

i tried this

```
@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=941748573937209344), name = 'kontrol', description='kontrol') 
async def check(ctx):
    channels = ctx.guild.text_channels
    for channel in channels:
        if channel.name.startswith('test-'):
            last_message = [msg async for msg in channel.history(limit=1)]
            print(last_message)
```

output :

```
[<Message id=1060085926157619221 channel=<TextChannel id=1060078850417111112 name='test-supraaaaaa' position=19 nsfw=False news=False category_id=941749835328012328> type=<MessageType.default: 0> author=<User id=323516141777715202 name='supraaaaaa' discriminator='0966' bot=False> flags=<MessageFlags value=0>>]
```

but there is no date last message created at and it gives this error when getting its id :

```
@tree.command(guild = discord.Object(id=941748573937209344), name = 'kontrol', description='kontrol') #guild specific slash command
async def check(ctx):
    channels = ctx.guild.text_channels
    for channel in channels:
        if channel.name.startswith('övgü-'):
            last_message = [msg async for msg in channel.history(limit=1)]
            print(last_message.id)
```

```
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'id'
```

Comment: Something may be missing in your question. In the code you provided, there is no reference to `id`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`last_message` is a list. A list does not have the `id` property.

What you are trying to do is to access the element in the list. There is only one, in the example you provided, so you should do:

```
print(last_message[0].id)
```

It means: In the list named `last_message`, access the first element (the `Message` object in your case) and from this object, access the `id` property in order to `print` it to `STDIN`.

---

To get the author's id, it is the same logic:

```
print(last_message[0].author.id)
```

Becasue `last_message.author` gives you the `User` object, which has the `id` property.

Concerning the date, it does not appear in the example you provided. I am not familiar with Discord's API, so you'll have to wait for another answer or look at the doc' by yourself.

Comment: thanks this works to get `last_message` `id` but how can i get `author` `id` and there is no date last message created at

Comment: thanks i solved it with the same logic
`print(last_message[0].created_at)`